# Netgear WNDR4000 open port 53

Tags: network, dns, ports, routing

Why is port 53 open on the WAN side of the router? And more importantly how do I close it?
Port 53 is not one of my forwarded ports.

Discovered by doing

```
nmap -pT:1-64 <my-external-IP> -Pn
```

Output:

```
[...]
PORT   STATE SERVICE
53/tcp open  domain
[...]
```

How can I close that security hole? (see [Listing of DNS vulnerabilities](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9470/listing-of-dns-vulnerabilities))

Comment: Is there an actual *service* responding on that domain? In that case, can you identify the actual service version that is being run?

Comment: Also, are you running custom firmware on the router (such as DD-WRT or OpenWRT)?

Comment: I am running the current netgear firmware for that router.

Answer (score 1):

It's for DNS.  I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest you probably want to leave it that way.

http://www.networkworld.com/community/blog/allow-both-tcp-and-udp-port-53-your-dns-serve

Comment: Why would I want to leave my DNS open on the WAN side?

Comment: because DNS is stateless and so it needs to be open for you to receive responses for your queries.  If you can restrict it to only receive them from your known upstream dns servers that's a good idea.

Comment: since when needs there be an open port on the WAN side to receive responses to TCP requests? I call bullsh1t on that.

Comment: I don't see why port 53 needs to be open unless you're a DNS server. It's not how DNS works, and I don't think TCP on port 53 is necessary at all.

Comment: well you probably should find a source to tell us why.  TCP is required for responses over 512 bytes:
https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5966
big responses are common for many dns server things (zone transfers being the most obvious example) but it's not limited to that.  There are legitimate reasons too.  Read the article I posted in my response.  IPv6 responses can be over 512 bytes, so can DNSSEC related things.  

I'd really appreciate it if you guys looked up sources for your answers.

Comment: That came off flippant and it's too late for me  to edit it but my point was - I'm no expert, but thought that was how DNS worked, if it's not, I'd like to learn why.

Comment: @pacifist apologies I didn't go into more detail, the comment section doesn't provide enough space. The article you linked is perfect if you're **running** a DNS server. I don't see where it indicates you need to have port 53 open in a *home network* where the odds are you don't run a DNS server, and only make DNS queries.

Comment: @pacifist afaik (and I might be wrong), DNS (over UDP or TCP) works like any other protocol - you open a socket to a particular server (which might result in an ephemeral port being open), and that particular server responds. A regular DNS query does not require port 53 to be open at all times.